# Tool for migrate SQL Server 2005 to SQL 2017

Tags: sql-server

There's any tools that can migrate SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2017?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can just restore a backup of the database. Was there anything outside of this that you were thinking of?

Comment: use `Data Migration Assistant` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: i find the fastest way or any tool that can direct upgrade 2005 to 2017

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DMA, Data Migration Assistant [DMA Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15)
You can do both an assessment of the migration, to have a preview of any features that could cause you issues after migration, and it can also do the migration for you.

Personally I only use the DMA to do the assessment and do the migration myself by using either backup/restore or incase there's a no downtime policy, some kind of mirroring.

I do suggest you make some kind of checklist of everything you have to do, and do a trial migration beforehand so there's less pressure when going to production.
Something like this could be useful to you : [Migration steps and checklist](https://www.sqlserverblogforum.com/dba/microsoft-sql-server-migration-plan-and-steps/)

Answer (score 1):

You could not simply restore database from SQL 2005 on to SQL 2017. I think that restore works only up to 2 versions, so you have to include SQL 2012.

If you do not have SQL 2012, you might think of scripting databases and using SSIS packages to export all data.

Also you need to script other database objects as users, SQL server jobs, linked servers etc

Comment: You can restore from `SQL Server 2005` to `SQL Server 2017`, it will be automatically upgraded

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right. Restore from SQL 2000 to SQL 2014 was not doable